# PostgreSQL, how to include the linux hostname inside the postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, centos

I'm looking for a way to include the linux hostname at the end a a postgres log event. I did some changes in the log_line_prefix section inside the `postgresql.conf` but I'm unable to include the hostname there using global variable, only add the actual text.

What I'm looking to do is something like below:

```
2022-12-07 22:10:32 UTC  [2112] LOG:  listening on .... "::", port 5432 .. linux_hostname
```

```
log_line_prefix -                  -- suffix ??? --
```

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y Problem™. Why do you need that in the log file on the server whose hostname you already know?

Comment: The thing is, the logs are exported to an Azure workspace (via custom log) to trigger an alert based on certain rules, but in that workspace we receive the log for multiples environment/resource groups and we need to identify the source, which is included in the hostname.

Comment: If you direct the Postgres log output to syslog you'll have your hostname for free

Comment: I am afraid that you will have to add the literal host name to `log_line_prefix`. It would be cool to have a placeholder for `cluster_name`, that could perhaps solve your problem.